# Python 3.3: Invalid Syntax error in line 7 of the below code

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
Weight = float(input("Enter weight in Kilograms: "))
Height = float(input("Enter height in meters: "))
BMI = (Weight / (Height**2))
print ("%.2f" %BMI)
if BMI < 18.5:
    print ("You are under weight")
elif BMI >= 18.5 and < 25.0:
    print ("You weight is normal")
elif BMI >= 25.0 and < 30.0:
    print ("You are overweight")
elif BMI >= 30.0:
    print ("You are overweight")
```

Getting invalid syntax at the line 
elif BMI >= 18.5 and < 25.0:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values is not a duplicate, but definitely explains how to do it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>`, `<`, and the rest are binary operators. It's looking for an operand on each side, and when it finds a keyword on its left `and < 25.0` throws a `SyntaxError`.

The normal way to do this is:

```
if BMI >= 18.5 and BMI < 25.0:
```

But there is a shortcut for inequalities:

```
if BMT < 18.5:
    # underweight
elif 18.5 <= BMI < 25.0:
    # normal
elif 25.0 <= BMI < 30:
    # overweight
elif 30 <= BMI:
    # super overweight
```